# Subscribed Singleton Class Events Not Firing

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, compact-framework

Subscribed Singleton Method Not Firing - nested windows forms

Adding support for a new mobile device to a legacy application.

Singleton Class Implemented Based On This Article
[Create Event on Singleton Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462050/create-event-on-singleton-class)

```
public sealed class Singleton
    {
        static readonly Singleton instance=new Singleton();

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Singleton()
        {
        }

        Singleton()
        {
        }

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

On creation, Each form subscribes a local method to the read method of the barcode object

```
singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormA_BarcodeReadMethod);
```

On close, Each form unsubscribes from the barcode object read method

singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormA_BarcodeReadMethod);

**Scenario #1**

- FormA is called from main menu form
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is null;
- FormA created
- FormA event subscribes to singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event

  'singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormA_BarcodeReadMethod);'
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is not null;
- Barcode scans and FormA_BarcodeReadMethod fires.
- FormA closed, FormA event unsubscribed to singleton

  BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormA_BarcodeReadMethod);
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is null;
- back to main menu form

There are 5 other forms which are called from the main screen and behave ok as above

**There is one instance where a form with a scanner subscription calls another form which also requires a scanner subscription**

**Scenario #2**

- FormB is called from main menu form
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is null;
- FormB created
- FormB event subscribes to singleton

  singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormB_BarcodeReadMethod);
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is not null;
- Barcode scans and FormB_BarcodeReadMethod fires.

*When processing the fired event, FormB calls FormC as follows*

- FormB event unsubscribed to singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event

  singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormB_BarcodeReadMethod);
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is null;
- FormC created
- FormC event subscribes to singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event

  singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormC_BarcodeReadMethod);
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is not null;
- Barcode scans and FormC_BarcodeReadMethod does not fire.
- FormC closed, FormC event unsubscribed to singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event

  singleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormC_BarcodeReadMethod);

singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is null;
- Control returns to FormB
- FormB event subscribes to singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan eventsingleton.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new BarcodeReadEventHandler(FormB_BarcodeReadMethod);
- singleton BarcodeReader.BarcodeScan event is not null;
- Barcode scans and FormB_BarcodeReadMethod fires.

The expect result would be that the subscribed FormC event would fire but it does not and I cannot figure out why that is.

Any help much appreciated.

**Response To Comment #1**

In FormB, a decision is made to call FormC
On FormB scanner event is unsubscribed

```
clsApplicationController.Instance.scanEngineIntermec.BarcodeRead -= new 
     BarcodeReadEventHandler(this.frmB_Intermec_OnRead); 
this.Update(); 
Application.DoEvents();
```

FormC is the called as follows

```
using (formC _formC = new formC())
{
_formC.cUser = _cUser;
var _result = _formC.ShowDialog();
if (_result != DialogResult.OK) return;
}
```

event is subscribed in FormC constructor

```
clsApplicationController.Instance.scanEngine.BarcodeRead += new 
BarcodeReadEventHandler(this.frmC_OnRead); 
this.Update(); 
Application.DoEvents();
```

**Response To Comment #2**

FormC event which is subscribed to but not firing

```
void formC_OnRead(object sender, BarcodeReadEventArgs bre) 
{ 
 try { 
      ProcessScan(bre.strDataBuffer, sender); 
     } 
 catch (Exception exp) 
 { 
   MessageBox.Show(exp.Message); 
 } 
}
```

the formC_OnRead method is subscribed to the Instance.scanEngineIntermec.BarcodeRead event in the FormC constructor.
ProcessScan is generic for use by all scanner types.
The same method and approach is implemented on the working forms

Comment: Is there any difference between `singleton.Instance.scanEngineIntermec` and `singleton.Instance.scanEngine`? Can you share the relevant code of FormB and Form C? Also the code of events in singleton?

Comment: apologies, singleton.Instance.scanEngineIntermec should have been replaced with singleton.Instance.scanEngine to make reading easier. post edited to remove singleton.Instance.scanEngineIntermec

Comment: Can you show the part, where scanEngine.BarcodeRead is fired? I guess, you have some Method like `OnBarcodeRead` or `FireOnBarcodeRead`?

Comment: Boydshane, please stop putting code in the comments, edit your question to add the new content.

Comment: Code removed from comments & added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically like to abstract barcode handling a bit so that the whole application is not dependent on a vendor SDK, making it easier to port the application if needed.  I'll skip the details on that tangent, but this approach also simplifies barcode handling throughout the app as well.

Keep your barcode manager singleton, and have him be the only entity that touches the barcode SDK objects.  Have your forms or other objects register their interest in receiving barcode notifications by calling your singleton Barcode Manager, and maintain them in a stack so you can route the barcode notifications to the topmost listener.  So in the scenario where you have a form A that handles barcodes that calls a dialog B that also handles dialogs, you don't have to micro-manage anything.  When a form or dialog is shown it calls `BarcodeManager.Instance.PushBarcodeListener(this)` in the Load or Activate.  And when it closes or deactivates you call `BarcodeManager.Instance.PopBarcodeListener(this)`.  If you use this consistently, Barcodemanager will know who the current / top listener is and notify just that object.

The listener itself is an SDK independent interface that any object that wants to receive barcode events implements.  Let's call it IBarcodeListener, and will define one method, that passes in barcode ready data:

```
void HandleBarcode(BarcodeReadEventArgs evt);
```

(You could even support listener traversal where the event bubbles down the stack until it is handled, but let's keep it simple for now).

Within your barcode manager singleton:

```
private void PushBarcodeListener(IBarcodeListener l)
{
   m_listeners.Push(l);
   if (m_listeners.Count == 1)
   {
      // as soon as you have an interested party, add your one and only 
      // event handler to the SDK object and enable it (the exact details
      // of this are SDK dependent).
   }
}

private void PopBarcodeListener(IBarcodeListener l)
{
   if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(l, m_listeners.Peek())
      Throw new Exception("Only the active BarcodeListener can be removed");

   m_listeners.Pop();
   if (m_listeners.Count == 0)
   {
      // if no one is interested in barcodes, stop listening by disabling the SDK
      // object and removing the event handler
   }
}
```

And of course, in the one-and-only SDK event handler, you notify the top listener like this:

```
   if (m_listeners.Count != 0)
      m_listeners.Peek().HandleBarcode(evt)
```

**Disclaimer, this code is not syntax checked, I just did this from memory.  You will need to fix typos.**

---

See comments for the context of this addition.

This is an example of some code I have used to run code on the UI thread "async".  Note that if called from the UI thread, it basically runs once all current windows messages have been processed by the message pump:

```
    public System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(System.Delegate method)
    {
        return base.MainForm.BeginInvoke(method);
    }

    public System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(System.Delegate method, params object[] args)
    {
        return base.MainForm.BeginInvoke(method, args);
    }
```

Note that "MainForm" is the reference to the root form in the application, and this code resides in my "app object", which is the root object of the whole application and is therefore accessible everywhere.

Comment: I fear, this will not fix the issue of boydshane. What he does not tell here, is that he is showing the FormC from inside the BarcodeRead handler in FormB. I recommand to decouple this.

Comment: @josef So you think the fact that he is making a blocking call within the event handler is messing with the SDK?  In that case, he should be using BeginInvoke to kick off the code that includes the ShowDialog, which will allow the event handler from the SDK to complete.

Comment: AsyncResult BeginInvoke is not available in Compact Framework 2

Comment: Control.BeginInvoke is not available in CF2?  I guess I was spoiled with CF3.5

Comment: delegate.BeginInvoke is not supported on the CF. I tried a delegate. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062930/threadstart-begininvoke-throws-notsupportedexception-on-compact-framework

Comment: I only maintain legacy CF 3.5 these days, but Control.BeginInvoke does work there.

Comment: PS - I added a sample above of this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have all working except the extending the peek method for to have HandleBarcode(evt). Looking at that at the moment but currently no sure how to do this.

Comment: currently not sure how to extend peek method. Assuming m_listeners is System.Collection.Stack and I am as far as having m_listeners.HandleBarcode(evt) so far.

Comment: If you are not using Generics, you will need to cast the object returned from Peek into a IBarcodeListener object and call HandleBarcode on that.

Comment: cheers @tcarvin, got that to working for Intermec SDK without Generics. Now to try the LXE SDK. Thinking implementing IBarcodeReader method as  HandleBarcode(string evtData); to keep the method generic on each form so as not to have to use device references on forms. HandleBarcode(BarcodeReadEventArgs evt would be specific to Intermec SDK and so different IBarcodeReader method required for each SDK event and then method required for each device type on each form,

Comment: I tend to create my own custom BarcodeEventArgs (inheriting from EventArgs) to accomplish that same goal because I often will use the symbology information as well.

Comment: This application is in a closed environment where the labels are printed on-demand and the symbologies are fixed and known. Now time to implement the POC findings into the application.. Again, really appreciate the help on this; wouldn't be this far without it.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you unsubscribe to a new EventHandler and not subtract the existing handler here:

clsApplicationController.Instance.scanEngineIntermec.BarcodeRead -= new BarcodeReadEventHandler(this.frmB_Intermec_OnRead);

Normally this should be:
   clsApplicationController.Instance.scanEngineIntermec.BarcodeRead -= this.frmB_Intermec_OnRead;

I am not sure, but -=new would unsubscribe a new EventHandler. Does that make sense? The -=new is used in all your forms?!

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
The failing code is:

```
    void Intermec_OnRead(object sender, BarcodeReadEventArgs bre)
    {
        try
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = bre.strDataBuffer;
            this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n" + this.Name;
            this.textBox1.Text += "\r\n" + sender.ToString();
            this.Update();

            if (_runFormC)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(this.textBox1.Text);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

                this.barcodeScanner_unSubscribe();

                using (FormC frmC = new FormC())
                {
                    var _result = frmC.ShowDialog();
                    if (_result != DialogResult.OK) return;
                }

                this.barcodeScanner_subscribe();
                this.textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
If formC is called from a Button_Click handler, everything is fine.

When I use a queue, a lock and a thread that launches formC if there is something in the queue, FormC works OK.
Changed all subscribe() unsubscribe() to be called fro Activated/Deactivate handlers.

Comment: Thanks josef; I have updated the code inline with your suggestion and the article. However, the result remains the same.

Comment: Can you supply a tailored down version of your complete project. The issue possibly  depends on the way you manage the handlers or whatever and now we only have some snippets.

Comment: Very basic version of app created which has same issue. subscribed scan events fire on FormA, FormB and FormC when called from FrmMain. Subscribed event does not fire on FormC when called from FormB. Project code available here https://app.box.com/s/ulp6z10uiah2pokbmhnwshzueci2whc5

Comment: The problem is that you call FormC from within the BarcodeRead EventHandler. So remove the Handler inside the Subscriber. What is the use for FormC? For example show a details page for a scanned item and then scan a location for this or what? +++ You need to decouple this, so it is not called from inside the handler.

Comment: Further on I would use the Form's Activated and Deactivate EventHandler to do the subscribe/unsubscribe. Not in Load and Close handler. I.e. The FormB is still loaded and not closed when you show FormC from code within FormB. But it is Deactivated and Activated.